# Explanation of this recursive function of Fast_Modular_Exponentiation

Tags: c, performance, recursion, exponentiation, modular

Here is a code form a udemy course that I am currently taking. This piece of code is a recursive solution to solve **`(a^n)%b`**.

```c
int fastExpo(int a, long long n, int MOD) {
    if(n == 0)
        return 1;

    /// (a^n) % MOD
    if(n % 2 == 0)
        /// a ^ n = ((a ^ 2) ^ (n/2))
        return fastExpo((1LL * a * a) % MOD, n / 2, MOD);

    /// a ^ n = a * (a ^ (n - 1))
    return (1LL * a * fastExpo(a, n - 1, MOD)) % MOD;
}
```

In this, I didn't understand this line of code: `(1LL * a * a) % MOD`. I understand that in case `n` is even, **`(x^n)%MOD = ((x^(n/2))^2)%MOD`**, but i didn't get why we are calculating **`(a^2)%MOD`**, while we should be calculating `((a^2)^(1/2))%MOD`. So, can someone explain me how this recursion step is correct and how recursion, in this case, is actually working?

Comment: Since `a` is an `int` you want the result of `a * a % MOD` and `a * fastExpo(a, n - 1, MOD)` to be of type `long long`, you multiply by `1LL` (long long suffix) to ensure type promotion to `long long` occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here when n is even then used

```
(x^n)%MOD = (((x^2)%MOD)^(n/2))%MOD
```

which is also true and in code use this.

Because algorithm says `(a ⋅ b) mod m = [(a mod m) ⋅ (b mod m)] mod m`

Find details [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) with exaplaination

Answer (score 0):

`((a^2)^(1/2))%MOD` is equal to `a%MOD`. So if `n` is odd algorithm multiply current value by `a` and subtract 1 from `n` to get even `n` on next step.

Full explanation of algorithm can be found here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation, see Right-to-left binary method